# CloneNotSupportedException for an enumeration

Tags: java, android, enums, clone

I got a strange error from my Android application reported by ACRA. It seems that clone() was called on an enumeration. Here's the stack trace:

```
        java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: Class doesn't implement Cloneable
            at java.lang.Object.clone(Object.java:155)
            at org.digitalcure.ccnf.app.io.data.Glyx.org.digitalcure.ccnf.app.io.data.Glyx[] values()(SourceFile:17)
            at org.digitalcure.ccnf.app.io.data.Glyx.org.digitalcure.ccnf.app.io.data.Glyx getForDatabaseValue(int)(SourceFile:140)
    ...
```

And this is the code of the enumeration:

```
package org.digitalcure.ccnf.app.io.data;

import org.digitalcure.ccnf.app.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

public enum Glyx {
    HIGH(-1),

    MEDIUM(0),

    LOW(1);

    private final int value;

    private Glyx(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Glyx getForNormedValue(final int value) {
        final Glyx[] array = Glyx.values();
        for (final Glyx candidate : array) {
            if (candidate.value == value) {
                return candidate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static Glyx getForDatabaseValue(final int value) {
        return getForNormedValue(value + HIGH.value);
    }

    // more code follows...
}
```

I removed the documentation and other uninteresting code, so line 17 refers to "public enum Glyx {" and line 140 to "return getForNormedValue(value + HIGH.value);".

I already checked my ProGuard configuration. It contains the following rule for enums:

```
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

I'm confused about the call of "clone()" on an enumeration and I cannot explain what happens here. What can I do to avoid this exception? Is there any explanation of this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Environment: Android 4.0.4, ZTE Grand X In

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803503/why-are-java-enums-not-clonable

Comment: Yes, I know that cloning of enums doesn't make sense. But the question is, why was "clone()" called at all?